# Combinations of letters "fi" and "fl" is not displayed by browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I have the following problem:

for my website I chose webfont **'Fira Sans Condensed'** from *Google Fonts* (Latin, Latin Extended, Cyrillic, Cyrillic Extended). For generating font formats I have used *Font Squirrel*, which generated for me files with ***.woff*** and **.woff2** extensions.

I include font with next css-code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'firasanscondensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('../fonts/firasanscondensed-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/firasanscondensed-regular.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'firasanscondensed';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts/firasanscondensed-bold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/firasanscondensed-bold.woff') format('woff');
}
```

```html
body {
  font-family: 'firasanscondensed', sans-serif;
}
```

My content displayed correctly except for combinations of letters "fi" and "fl". For example: "Wi-fi" dispays like "Wi- ".

To solve the problem I tried to include font with more font-extensions (***.eot***,**.ttf**) and in a different order, but situation has not changed.

Then I used *Google Fonts* method of including: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans+Condensed:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">`. With this method my problem is solving! But for me it's in principle to include fonts locally.

I see the issue in the following browsers: Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87; Mozilla Firefox 51.0.1. In IE10 the problem does not appear!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I have used the snippet to insert `css-code`.

Answer (score 3):

Common ligatures are activated by default, but some fonts don't support them. Try to **disable** them with `font-feature-settings:"liga" 0;`
This worked for me.

Comment: This is the answer. The problem op is having is with the font not supporting stylistic orthographic ligatures.

Answer (score 0):

Try this against the element in which the fonts are rendering (or body).

```
body {  
  font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
}
```

You might need vendor prefixes:

```
body  {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
  -moz-font-feature-settings:    "liga" 1;
  -ms-font-feature-settings:     "liga" 1;
  font-feature-settings:         "liga" 1;
}
```

The features that can be toggled this way (if the font supports them) are..

- liga: standard ligatures
- dlig: discretionary ligatures
- onum: old style figures
- lnum: lining figures
- tnum: tabular figures
- zero: slashed zero
- frac: fractions
- sups: superscript
- subs: subscript
- smcp: small caps
- c2sc: small capitals from capitals
- case: case-sensitive forms
- hlig: historical ligatures
- calt: contextual alternates
- swsh: swashes
- hist: historical forms
- ss**: stylistic sets
- kern: kerning
- locl: localized forms
- rlig: required ligatures
- medi: medial forms
- init: initial forms
- isol: isolated forms
- fina: final forms
- mark: mark
- mkmk: mark-to-mark positioning

They can even be combined into one rule like this:

```
.element {
  font-feature-settings:"liga" 1, "dlig" 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it doesn't help. I tried different combinations of `font-feature-settings` property.