# Fira sans not looking consistent fi and fl are not separated and look bolder

Tags: css, font-face, google-fonts

**The goal is to remove the bold letters from fl and fi in the text**

[image]
chrome 61

I was able to reproduce the issue in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/vWgEGB

basically fira sans not applying any `letter-spacing` to the chars and they chars are bold. No idea why.

this is how it looks on firefox 56:
[image]

Comment: What browser are you using for the letter spacing? In Firefox it looks fine. Also, they aren't separating (without increased letter spacing) because it could be a typographic ligature and built into the font. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature

Comment: well but on the page I linked, they look bolder as well. I don't mind soo much them sticking together. Even though I actually do mind. but that they are bold as well? I could reproduce in both, chrome and firefox.

Comment: Related: [Combinations of letters “fi” and “fl” is not displayed by browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42269783/1016716) and [How to correct the ligatures of 'fi' and 'fl' in case of larger letter-spacing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42934280/1016716)

Comment: @MrLister none of those seem to work for me. Still bold

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a CSS attribute designed for controlling how ligatures are generated automatically by browsers.

Try adding:

`font-variant-ligatures: none;`

to your paragraph element.

See this codepen: https://codepen.io/jossnaz/pen/vWgEGB

For the issue where you want to control character spacing, and your source text is composed like "truffle shuffle" with separate F and L characters, this will prevent the browser from generating ligatures and apply spacing as you'd probably expect.

---

However, this is not the only issue you are running into in your site!

In your page, the text is actually using the Unicode **ﬁ** and **ﬂ** ligature characters (U+FB01 and U+FB02). The browser will not separate these back into separate characters, and they are *not* included by the Google Fonts API. This is possibly some plugin in your CMS automatically converting ligatures, or perhaps the result of copying and pasting from an editor.

See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqmLLZ for an example of this.

These ligature characters are not included in the webfont - the Latin ligatures are at U+FB00-FB06 and either the font or Google's Font API doesn't include them.
As a result, they are switching to the fallback font, which in this case is specified as the generic `sans-serif` - probably Arial or Helvetica.
They're not *bold* per se, but they're heavier than Fira Sans.

Comment: You had a link in the bounty to your site, I used the Chrome dev tools to add the font-variant-ligatures attribute to an element, and there was no change. So I looked at the source and the ligatures existed in the plain text representation.

Comment: just for completeness here is a unicode fl: `ﬂagged` you can notice because you can only select `fl` together. You cannot only select `f` or `l`

Comment: Additionally, the ligature characters may in fact be in the font, but Google appears to have pre-trimmed their fonts to fixed Unicode ranges, excluding the ligature characters.If you have the font installed locally it might actually look ok.